# Creating an array from a nested dictionary

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to extract a nested dictionary from a DataSnapshot.

```
var query = admin.database().ref("meetings").orderByChild("deadline");
query.once("value").then((snapshot) => 
{
    snapshot.forEach((child) =>
    {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
    }
}
```

This code prints this:

```
{ 
    '82BE0F33-6812-4EFF-8CB4-FABDACA2B329': 
    {
        deadline: 1509634558,
        name: 'cfedfgh',
        users: 
        { 
            '8YUDtUJuIde8fLaHCfeuSNsHUyq2': '1',
            DVAYNspxcGfB001RSkq3S8cxvsH3: '1',
            fJXgRJBoFAU0SmA2Zhn4DpdyLGh1: '1' 
        } 
    }
}
```

How would I go about creating an array of dictionary users values? Or access them at all.

Doing `console.log(child.child("users").val());` gives me a `null`.

Database structure:

[image: database structure screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`DataSnapshot#child()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#child) will give you another `DataSnapshot` for the location at the specified relative path. Therefore, a `DataSnapshot` with children is considered a parent node so doesn't have a specific value, so `val()` won't work here.

In order to convert your `users` value into any array, you'll need to iterate over each child underneath it and pass the key into an array, so something like this:

```
snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    let users = [];
    if (child.child("users").exists()) {
      child.child("users").forEach((userSnapshot) => {
        users.push(userSnapshot.key);
      });
    }
    console.log(users);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `snapshot` is an array of objects, you can use the following.  This will give you all of the users for each record.

```
const users = [].concat.apply([], snapshot.map(row => {
  return Object.keys(row).map(key => {
    return row[key].users
  })
}))

console.log(users)
```